# How do I redirect a www url to a no-www url using nginx-ingress-controller?

Tags: redirect, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to get the url **www.example.com** to **redirect** itself to **example.com** while preserving everything about the original request in *k8s 1.11.1*

I am attempting to do this using a simple Ingress, and am then using annotations to redirect it.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://example.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "True"
  name: example-redirect
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example
          servicePort: http
```

The issue here is that I don't want to have any rules/backend. I simply want to redirect www.example.com to example.com using an Ingress, but k8s Ingresses require me to have rules. Are there any workarounds here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource has strongly defined prerequisites for the relevant API [specification](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#ingress-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io). You may exclude `rules:` field from the general configuration, however `backend:` should be definitely specified, in the way that [Nginx Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) could route network traffic to the target endpoint in case no rules declared or matched.

Whenever you create any specific settings for Nginx Ingress controller either via [Annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/) or [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/), both of the options doing the same job of applying some specific configuration to the underlying `nginx.conf` file which resides on `nginx-ingress-controller` Pod. It means that Ingress controller applies `server {}` and `location {}` blocks into the corresponded Nginx web server Pod for particular host:

```
server {
        server_name www.example.com ;

        listen 80;

        listen [::]:80;

        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

        listen 443  ssl http2;

        listen [::]:443  ssl http2;

        .............

        location / {

            set $namespace      "default";
            set $ingress_name   "example-redirect";
            set $service_name   "example";
            set $service_port   "http";
            set $location_path  "/";
            ......................
                   }
       }
```

Therefore, I suppose that you can capture `nginx.conf` file, based on Ingress resource configuration and then apply it independently inside Ingress controller Pod.

I assume that you may consider also to use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"` [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#redirect-fromto-www) in order to achieve the goal in current scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Following should do:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($host = 'www.example.com' ) {
        rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri permanent;
      }
  name: example-redirect
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: example-tls
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: example
          servicePort: http
```